# SQL Add column to result containing sum of rows in other table where matches query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a SQL query that will get the sum of rows in a different table where the `uuid` column matches the `post` column in the `type` column and append that value to the results' row. The column `type` in the `votes` table has values of 0 and 1, 0 meaning -1 from the sum and 1 meaning +1 to the sum of the score. Once all of that is completed I was looking to sort the results in the `score` column to have the highest score first.

If you would like an SQL fiddle, the link is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc490b/1/0

The shortened version of table schema for the `posts` table is:

```
 uuid varchar(256)
 contents text
 author varchar(256)
 comment varchar(256)
 timestamp varchar(256)
 removed varchar(256)
```

And the schema of the `votes` table is:

```
 user varchar(256)
 post varchar(256)
 type int(1)
```

And since this is part the the query, this is the schema of the `follows` table:

```
 user varchar(256)
 target varchar(256)
```

My current query to get the feed of posts is the following, I am looking to base if off of this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
 WHERE timestamp <= ? 
   AND removed IS NULL 
   AND comment IS NULL 
   AND author IN (SELECT target 
                    FROM follows 
                   WHERE user = ? 
                   UNION 
                  SELECT ? AS target) 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT 25;
```

The final result from the query I'm expecting is the following:

```
| uuid | contents | author | comment | timestamp  | removed | score (DESC) |
| p12c | Hi!      | u7h34  | NULL    | 1560269397 | NULL    | 451          |
| p100 | Chicken  | u211f  | NULL    | 1560269417 | NULL    | 14           |
```

DDLs:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `follows`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `votes`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;

CREATE TABLE `follows` (
  `user` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `target` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `follows` (`user`, `target`) VALUES
('user-uuid2', 'user-uuid1');

CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `user` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `post` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `votes` (`user`, `post`, `type`) VALUES
('user-uuid2', 'post-uuid9', 0),
('user-uuid2', 'post-uuid9', 1),
('user-uuid2', 'post-uuid8', 1);

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `uuid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `contents` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `removed` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`uuid`, `contents`, `author`, `comment`, `timestamp`, `removed`) VALUES
('post-uuid1', 'Hello world1!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184505', NULL),
('post-uuid2', 'Hello world2!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184506', NULL),
('post-uuid3', 'Hello world3!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184507', NULL),
('post-uuid4', 'Hello world4!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184508', NULL),
('post-uuid5', 'Hello world5!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184509', NULL),
('post-uuid6', 'Hello world6!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184510', NULL),
('post-uuid7', 'Hello world7!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184511', NULL),
('post-uuid8', 'Hello world8!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184512', NULL),
('post-uuid9', 'Hello world9!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184513', NULL),
('post-uuid10', 'Hello world10!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184514', NULL),
('post-uuid11', 'Hello world11!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184515', NULL),
('post-uuid12', 'Hello world12!', 'user-uuid1', NULL, '1560184516', NULL);
```

Comment: Give me a second to make a SQL fiddle.

Comment: No rush. We're here all week.

Comment: Added the link.

Comment: I don't see Hi / Chicken in this data set; just a lot of very un-community friendly strings. But, hey, it's still only Tuesday.

Comment: Oh, I just went through and swapped out the UUIDs for more readable strings.

Comment: Well, let us know when the question (i.e. the desired  result) matches up with the data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you just need the `SUM` of a `CASE` expression.

(I had to comment out the `WHERE` clause because it was eliminating the posts with votes.)

```
SELECT 
   p.uuid,
   p.contents,
   p.author,
   p.comment,
   p.timestamp,
   p.removed,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN v.type = 0 THEN -1 ELSE v.type END,0)) as Score
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN votes v
    ON v.post = p.uuid
-- WHERE timestamp <= '1560184509' 
   AND removed IS NULL 
   AND comment IS NULL 
   AND author IN (SELECT target 
                    FROM follows 
                   WHERE user = '2452be00-5b48-4c09-8abb-21d469bc8e11' 
                   UNION 
                  SELECT '2452be00-5b48-4c09-8abb-21d469bc8e11' AS target) 
 GROUP BY
   p.uuid,
   p.contents,
   p.author,
   p.comment,
   p.timestamp,
   p.removed
 ORDER 
    BY Score DESC 
 LIMIT 25;
```

Your Fiddle back to you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61068/8/0

Comment: Except the fiddle's moved on. I know, it's all very confusing.

Comment: This was the answer, it works - and here's the fiddle for the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc490b/10/0

Comment: By any chance is there a way to default the score column to 0 and not null?

Comment: @FiredareGames, sorry. It was deployment day and I got busy there. See the edit to the answer.